# What is the first episode where David Tennant isn't "sorry"

Tags: doctor-who

Watching this [This Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHVW-S9JkKA) got me thinking, is Tennant ever not "sorry".
I don't want a list, I just want a yes or a no. He is sorry 120 times in about 50 episodes. Is there even one example of David Tennant not being "sorry" for an entire episode.

Obviously, only full episodes that have David Tennant as the Doctor counts.

Comment: This is really just a rant, not a serious question.

Comment: Trust me, my rants are undeniable. This is a question. David Tennant is known for his expressions/mannerisms.

Comment: Funny video, but at least one of those is him saying "sorry?" as in "pardon?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  Series 2, Episode 7 - The Idiot's Lantern.  [Doesn't say sorry once](http://who-transcripts.atspace.com/2006/transcripts/207_theidiotslantern.html).

Comment: Looks like Magpie steals the line.